# CONNECTION_FAILED while creating room Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

This is my function to quickGame

```
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 1, 0);
RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
switchToScreen(R.id.screen_wait);
//keepScreenOn();
//resetGameVars();
getGamesClient().createRoom(rtmConfigBuilder.build());
```

and onRoomCreated where game stops

```
@Override
    public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRoomCreated(" + statusCode + ", " + room + ")");
        if (statusCode != GamesClient.STATUS_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "*** Error: onRoomCreated, status " + statusCode);
            showGameError();
            return;
        }
        showWaitingRoom(room);
    }
```

Im getting `statusCode = 7000` which is `STATUS_REAL_TIME_CONNECTION_FAILED`, and `room = null` so i think problem is in quickGame function.

```
D/Multiplayer(24221): Sign-in succeeded.
D/Multiplayer(24221): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=10001, resp=RESULT_CANCELED
D/Multiplayer(24221): GameHelper: onActivityResult: request code not meant for us. Ignoring.
W/Multiplayer(24221): *** invitation inbox UI cancelled, 0
D/Multiplayer(24221): GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=10000, resp=RESULT_OK
D/Multiplayer(24221): GameHelper: onActivityResult: request code not meant for us. Ignoring.
D/Multiplayer(24221): Select players UI succeeded.
D/Multiplayer(24221): Invitee count: 1
D/Multiplayer(24221): Creating room...
D/Multiplayer(24221): Room created, waiting for it to be ready...
D/Multiplayer(24221): onRoomCreated(7000, null)
E/Multiplayer(24221): *** Error: onRoomCreated, status 7000
W/ResourceType(24221): getEntry failing because entryIndex 13 is beyond type entryCount 1
W/ResourceType(24221): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b000d (t=10 e=13) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(24221): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
W/PicturePileLayerContent(24221): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
W/PicturePileLayerContent(24221): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
W/PicturePileLayerContent(24221): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
```

Im comparing my source code with google example, but no effects
I've Google Play Services 4.0 on tablet and latest sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed google play services.apk from internet and that was the reason. I wait for update from Google Play and everything is working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you turn on multiplayer in the Google Play Developer Console?

> **Enabling multiplayer support**
>
> To integrate game services multiplayer support, such as player matchmaking, you must enable multiplayer settings. Currently, only real-time multiplayer for Android is supported.
>
> To enable multiplayer:
>
> Open the Games with Game Services page from the Google Play Developer Console, and select your game.
>   Open the Linked apps page for your game, then switch the multplayer setting to ON.
>   Click Save as draft to store your settings.

Source: https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#enabling_multiplayer_support

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know - i figured out what my problem is .. well sort of..

It turns out the problem is AdMob in my case - it was initially integrated as a separate library and when i added GooglePlus to the game started seeing lots of stuff in the console.

I was confused that the problem was GooglePlus (throwing the messages you are seeing about missing resources) - but it is the AdMob part that is doing that.

Nevertheless even after figuring this out GooglePlus operations do not function.

The strangest thing is that they work under an old HTC Sense (2.2) but not on any 4.x device..

I just ripped the whole thing out - lost two days in it .. for a single +1 BUTTON.